# IntelliJ IDEA;Webstorm: Live Templates with selection

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

In IntelliJ IDEA/Webstorm I want to make sure of the live templates variable `$SELECTION$`.

But practically how is this used?  After I select some text and go to use the live template, typing a value simply replaces the selected text instead of filtering the list.

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong (or do not understand how LT for selection work). Please show screenshots of your LT and steps you do when you are trying to use it.

Comment: Live templates that use $SELECTION$ should be applied via Code/Surround with live template (Ctrl+Alt+J). See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/creating-code-constructs-using-surround-templates.html

Comment: Official tutorial for Live Templates: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @lena Thank you, that's just what I needed... I've been ignoring surround templates

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by pressing **Ctrl+ Alt + J** in keyboard and select the live template.